# Rails strong params giving wrong number of arguments exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm trying to implement simple authorization following by certain tutorial.

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController

    layout 'public'
    def auth_user
        user = User.authenticate(login_params)
        if user
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to(:action => 'home')
        else
            flash[:notice] = "wrong username or password"
            flash[:color]= "invalid"
            render "login"  
        end
    end

  private

  def login_params
    params.require(:login_data, :password)
  end

end
```

and getting the exception at params.require saying 'wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)'.
can't understand, what am I doing wrong?
rails 4.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `require` method, or more specifically [`ActionController::Parameters#require`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/require), only takes a param key as argument.

As you can see from the Rails 4.1.1 source code:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb, line 172
def require(key)
  self[key].presence || raise(ParameterMissing.new(key))
end
```

Comment: was it modified since rails 4.0.0? cause this is the only explanation why it works with the tutorial I'm using

Comment: I don't think so. The method looked very similar on the 4.0 stable branch: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L182-L189

Comment: Are you sure your tutorial is not using `#permit` with two arguments rather than `#require`?

Comment: I can't find the url for tutorial, but yes, I'm sure. here it is   `private

  def admin_user_params
    params.require(:admin_user).permit(:first_name, :last_name,
      :email, :username, :password)
  end`

Comment: There you go. It's `#permit` that's taking several arguments in the snippet you posted, not `#require`.

Comment: ah, you're right, my shame. everywhere require is mentioned in this tutorial it accepts only one argument. I don't see the point of this then. what if I want more required params than one?